# javascript function with ajax and php does not work as I want

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I have the following function in javascript that calls the ajax which calls the php,
I would like to pass by parameter to the javascript function, the php page that i want to access and 
the div id, all from html, follows the code that I have:

/*--------------------------------------------------javascript----------------------------------*/

```
function getXMLHttp() 
{
var xmlHttp

try
{
//Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
catch(e)
{
//Internet Explorer
try
{
  xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e)
{
  try
  {
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
    return false;
  }
}
}
return xmlHttp;
}

function MakeRequest() 
{
var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
{
  HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
}

xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php", true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function HandleResponse(response)
{
document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
```

/*--------------------------------------------------php----------------------------------*/

```
<?php
echo "This is a php response to your request!!!!!!";
?>
```

/*--------------------------------------------------html----------------------------------*/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='ajax.js'></script>
    <title>PHP AJAX Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='button' onclick='MakeRequest();' value='Use AJAX!!!!'/>
    <div id='ResponseDiv'>
      This is a div to hold the response.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thank you enormously ...

Comment: do you have a reason you want to write your own ajax js library?  download jQuery otherwise.  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ResponseDiv").load("ajax.php");
});

Comment: Don't do your own home-grown ajax handlers. Use jquery or mootools. They'll make your life MUCH easier/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, I'm not going to tell you that you can't re-invent the wheel if you want to. ^^

```
function getXMLHttp() 
{
    var xmlHttp

    try
    {
        //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch(e)
    {
        //Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function MakeRequest(page, obj) 
{
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText, obj);
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", page, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function HandleResponse(response, obj)
{
    document.getElementById(obj).innerHTML = response;
}
```

Here is the HTML body component. Notice I used "quotes" and not 'apostrophes'.

```
<input type="button" onclick="MakeRequest('ajax.php', 'ResponseDiv');" value="Use AJAX!!!!"/>
<div id='ResponseDiv'>
  This is a div to hold the response.
</div>
```

Comment: kkkkkkkkk, perfect Tanoro, thank you enormously, I can't download the library because the focus is performance, it is an administrative panel.. you saved my day, hehehe